# I want to print the line before and after match

Tags: python, parsing

I am wanting to create a .py file that can open a .txt document and read in the data, split it into words, then I would like to be able to search for a date and time. The time can vary and may not be exact so it could fall in between two times. I would like to print the two lines that fall before and after the searched date/time.

I am using this so far:

```
temp_list =[]
open_file = open(temp_data, "r")
contents = open_file.readlines()[57:] #skipping first 57 lines.
for i in range(len(contents)):
words = contents[i].split()
if (len(words) == 43) and (words[0] == date) and (words[1] < time): #using 43 will read/print only lines that have 43 words in them as they are the lines with important data.
    print words[0], "|", words[1], "|", words[12],  "F"
```

I am completely new to coding and have looked everywhere but am still not able to find anything. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

EDIT(it will not allow me to post pictures of txt file for some reason without reputation):

> 2010-10-02 19:00:01.15 M  ~D 0 2 1 1 2 1  -38.4  22.7   3.7 N N  20  -1.1  29.2   0 -99.9 0 24.1  16.0     3    71     0 000 172 0284 0473 0949 1023 0224 0228   0.0 080 13415 3 0710~  0  0 F M
>
> 2010-10-02 19:30:00.47 M  ~D 0 2 1 1 2 1  -40.2  21.7   2.3 N N  21  -1.6  29.5   0 -99.9 0 24.1  22.0     3    71     0 000 172 0301 0470 0949 1023 0191 0201   0.0 070 13416 3 0444~  0  0 F M
>
> 2010-10-02 20:00:01.73 M  ~D 0 2 1 1 2 0  -28.6  20.6   2.1 N N  22  -1.8  29.1   0 -99.9 0 24.1  23.9     3    74     0 000 172 0241 0474 0949 1023 0187 0193   0.0 067 13417 1 0003~  0  0 F M

Comment: What is the meaning of the numbers 57 and 43 in your code? "Magic numbers" are generally discouraged in programming.

Comment: 43 is the number of words in a line (ignoring all lines who do not have 43 words in them - which means there is no data in those lines). 57 is skipping the first 57 lines as it does not have any data in them.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that will return `True` if the line is a match. Looks like your `if` statement is doing that. If it returns True, then print the lines `contents[i-2:i+2]`.

Comment: I am confused on how to write the code for this :(

The contents needs to be words 0, 1, and 12 since the whole line includes 43 different words.

Comment: It would help if you posted the .txt file so people can better understand your problem.

Comment: The sample of the txt file is added in original post. There should be 43 words per line (separated by spaces since text is wrapped on this page).